# How can I use a datepicker in ActiveAdmin without rewriting the create form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

My ActiveAdmin model creation forms (ie. `/admin/<model>/new`) are using an awkward set of dropdowns for dates and datetimes.

I'd like to use pickers instead. But all the documentation I've found about using a datetime picker appears to require rewriting the whole form. There doesn't seem to be a way to change just one input, nor an equivalent of `preserve_default_filters!`.

I'd like to either change the default for all date and datetime columns, something like...

```
config.datepicker = ...
```

Or per column, like...

```
column :signed_up, as: :datetime_picker
```

---

***EDIT***

By default I get new and edit forms equivalent to this.

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors
  f.inputs
  f.actions
end
```

If I want to change `signed_up` to use a datepicker, I have to repeat all the columns supplied by default just to change the input type of one column.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Thing do
  form do |f|
    t.semantic_errors
    t.input :name
    t.input :this
    t.input :that
    t.input :signed_up, as: :datepicker
    t.input :other
    t.input :thing
    t.input :left
    t.input :right
    t.actions
  end
end
```

That's a lot of unnecessary repetition, and the formatting doesn't come out right. I'm looking for a way to change the input presentation of one column, or one type, without having to manually write the whole form every time.

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to? Does input, as: :[datepicker](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#datepicker) not meet your needs? https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#datepicker

Comment: @PiersC Right now I'm using the default form. If I write a form/inputs block to change one input I'll need to rewrite them all.

Comment: Ah. The default form is delegated entirely to Formtastic so you will need to monkeypatch it, perhaps something like https://gist.github.com/voldy/271377

Answer (score 2):

Try the DateNTimePickerActiveAdmin Rubygem. It works really well and is customisable according to your project.

You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/NikhithaGraceJosh/date_n_time_picker_activeadmin

From the docs:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'date_n_time_picker_activeadmin'
```

**Code Sample (In your form)**

```
f.input :column_name, as: :datetimepicker
```

**CSS**

In active_admin.scss, add the line,

```
@import date_n_time_picker_activeadmin
```

**JS**

In active_admin.js, add the line,

```
//= require date_n_time_picker_activeadmin
```

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to monkey patch Active Admin behavior, to use `:datepicker` instead of `:date_select`.

In your `config/application.rb`, add following patches

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

// Start patch

module ActiveAdminFormBuilderPatch
  def default_input_type(*_args, **_kwargs)
    ret = super
    ret == :date_select ? :datepicker : ret
  end
end

ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder.include ActiveAdminFormBuilderPatch

// end patch

module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    // configs
  end
end
```

## Note

Confirmed this to be working on activeadmin version `2.9.0`.

Comment: A cleaner patch than my approach.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work. The patched default_input_type is never called.

Comment: weird... maybe version problem? I'll append version info in the answer..

Answer (score 0):

I used [`activeadmin_addons`](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons) which does a lot of useful things, including using [DateTimePicker for input](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons#date-time-picker-input), but not filters.

To get filters I use [`active_admin_datetimepicker`](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_datetimepicker) which makes [jQuery DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) available for inputs (:date_time_picker) and filters (:date_time_range). Then I monkey patched ActiveAdmin to use it by default.

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb

# Make the default filter type for a DateTime to be the DateTimeRange picker.
class ActiveAdmin::Filters::FormBuilder
  protected

    alias_method :original_default_input_type, :default_input_type

    def default_input_type(method, options = {})
      case column_for(method)&.type
      when :datetime
        return :date_time_range
      end

      original_default_input_type(method, options)
    end
end
```